# difference between kotlin also, apply, let, use, takeIf and takeUnless in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-function

I read many Kotlin documents about these items. But I can't understand so clearly.

What is the use of Kotlin **let**, **also**, **takeIf** and **takeUnless** in detail?

I need an example of each item. Please don't post the Kotlin documentation. I need a real-time example and use cases of these items.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**let, also, apply, takeIf, takeUnless** are extension functions in Kotlin.

To understand these function you have to understand **Extension functions** and **Lambda functions** in Kotlin.

**Extension Function:**

By the use of extension function, we can create a function for a class without inheriting a class.

> Kotlin, similar to C# and Gosu, provides the ability to extend a class
> with new functionality without having to inherit from the class or use
> any type of design pattern such as Decorator. This is done via special
> declarations called extensions. Kotlin supports extension functions
> and extension properties.

So, to find if only numbers in the `String`, you can create a method like below without inheriting `String` class.

```
fun String.isNumber(): Boolean = this.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex())
```

you can use the above **extension function** like this,

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
println(phoneNumber.isNumber())
```

which is prints `true`.

**Lambda Functions:**

Lambda functions are just like Interface (contains only one method. Also called as Single Abstract Method) in Java. From Java 8 lambdas are available in java also. In Kotlin lambdas used everywhere. Mostly lambdas passed as a parameter in a function.

Example:

```
fun String.isNumber(block: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    return if (this.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex())) {
        block()
        true
    } else false
}
```

You can see, the block is a lambda function and it is passed as a parameter. You can use the above function like this,

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
phoneNumber.isNumber {
   println("Block executed")
}
```

The above function will print like this,

```
Block executed
```

I hope, now you got an idea about Extension functions and Lambda functions. Now we can go to Extension functions one by one.

**let**

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R = block(this)
```

Two Types T and R used in the above function.

```
T.let
```

`T` could be any object like String, number, or any type. So you can invoke this function with any objects.

```
block: (T) -> R
```

You can see the lambda function In parameter of let the invoking object is passed as a parameter of the function. So you can use the invoking class object inside the function. then it returns the `R` (another object).

Example:

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
val numberAndCount: Pair<Int, Int> = phoneNumber.let { it.toInt() to it.count() }
```

In above example let takes **String** as a parameter of its lambda function and it returns **Pair** in return.

In the same way, other extension functions works.

**also**

```
public inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T { block(this); return this }
```

extension function `also` takes the invoking class as a lambda function parameter and returns nothing.

Example:

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
phoneNumber.also { number ->
    println(number.contains("8"))
    println(number.length)
 }
```

**apply**

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

Same as also but the same invoking object passed as the function so you can use the functions and other properties without calling it or parameter name.

Example:

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
phoneNumber.apply { 
    println(contains("8"))
    println(length)
 }
```

You can see in the above example the functions of String class directly invoked inside the lambda funtion.

**takeIf**

```
public inline fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? = if (predicate(this)) this else null
```

Example:

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
val number = phoneNumber.takeIf { it.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex()) }
```

In above example `number` will have a string of `phoneNumber` only it matches the `regex`. Otherwise, it will be `null`.

**takeUnless**

```
public inline fun <T> T.takeUnless(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? = if (!predicate(this)) this else null
```

It is the reverse of takeIf.

Example:

```
val phoneNumber = "8899665544"
val number = phoneNumber.takeUnless { it.matches("[0-9]+".toRegex()) }
```

`number` will have a string of `phoneNumber` only if not matches the `regex`. Otherwise, it will be `null`.

Answer (score 52):

### Preamble

`let`, `also`, `takeIf` and `takeUnless` is called ***on*** something. This thing is called a *receiver*.

Example: `myVar.let { ... }`
`myVar` is the *receiver* of the function call.

### let

`public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R = block(this)`

Take the *receiver* and pass it to a function passed as a parameter. Return the result of the function.

```
val myVar = "hello!"
myVar.let { println(it) } // Output "hello!"
```

You can use `let` for null safety check:

```
val myVar = if (Random().nextBoolean()) "hello!" else null
myVar?.let { println(it) } // Output "hello!" only if myVar is not null
```

### also

`public inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T { block(this); return this }`

Execute the function passed with the *receiver* as parameter and return the *receiver*.
It's like let but always return the *receiver*, not the result of the function.

You can use it for doing something on an object.

```
val person = Person().also {
  println("Person ${it.name} initialized!")
  // Do what you want here...
}
```

### takeIf

`public inline fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? = if (predicate(this)) this else null`

Return the *receiver* if the function (predicate) return true, else return null.

```
println(myVar.takeIf { it is Person } ?: "Not a person!")
```

### takeUnless

`public inline fun <T> T.takeUnless(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? = if (!predicate(this)) this else null`

Same as `takeIf`, but with predicate reversed. If true, return null, else return the *receiver*.

```
println(myVar.takeUnless { it is Person } ?: "It's a person!")
```

### Help

- You can use https://try.kotlinlang.org/ for testing easily. You can find examples [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/khtmi67bs418h4j2ocpiji089a/dipu5dmhj7orvf1g9c8q7604t9).
- You can checkout the source of the standard lib [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/stdlib). `let`, `also`, `takeIf` and `takeUnless` [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.1/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt).

Comment: Taking a course on Kotlin on hyperskill.org and didn't understand take, takeUnless, ... This, together with the accepted answer made it so clear -- love you !!