# Kotlin: What is the difference between Apply and Also

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between apply and also. From what I know the following code does the same thing:

**apply**

```
val person = Person().apply {
    name = "Tony Stark"
    age = 52
    // More such stuff
}
```

**also**

```
val person = Person().also {
  it.name = "Tony Stark"
  it.age = 52
  // More such stuff
}
```

Is there any difference and should I use one over the other? Also, are there some cases where one would work and the other won't?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977011/example-of-the-different-of-run-let-apply-also-and-with-on-kotlin

Comment: Your example usage code is different, thus I would conclude that there *is* a difference between the functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [differnce between kotlin also, apply, let, use, takeIf and takeUnless in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582732/differnce-between-kotlin-also-apply-let-use-takeif-and-takeunless-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**TL;DR Difference**

The `also` function takes a lambda in which you refer to the object you called the function on (receiver `T`) with either `it` (implicit name) or a custom name.

```
val person = Person().also {
    it.name = "Tony Stark"
}
```

With `apply`, on the other hand, a function literal **with receiver** is used so inside the passed in lambda you can access the receiver’s members directly, as you see in the following. The receiver can be referenced by `this`.

```
val person = Person().apply {
    name = "Tony Stark"
}
```

---

#### also

Declaration:

```
inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T (source)
```

Calls the specified function block **with `this` (the receiver) value as its argument** and returns `this` (the receiver) value.

#### apply

Declaration:

```
inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T (source)
```

Calls the specified function block **with `this` value as its receiver** and returns `this` (the receiver) value.

### when to use what

Usage examples are explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977011/example-of-the-different-of-run-let-apply-also-and-with-on-kotlin).

Answer (score 52):

**Short answer:** `also` was introduced for semantic reasons.

**Long answer:**

If you use `apply` you always refer to the receiver with `this`.

```
val person = Person().apply {
    name = "Tony Stark" // this. can be omitted
    age = 52 // this. can be omitted
    // ...
}
```

This way you don't have to repeat `person` several times as shown here:

```
person.name = "Tony Stark"
person.age = 52
```

If the block becomes longer you may want to give `this` a name. That's why `also` was introduced. Now you can refer to the receiver either by `it` or an explicit name. This is especially useful if you want to use another name than (in this case `person`) before:

```
val person = Person().also { newPerson ->
  newPerson.name = "Tony Stark"
  newPerson.age = 52
  // ...
}
```

So, depending on how well you code should be readable you can always use one or the other.

Comment: In case of block longer then we may use this, but then the question is why apply? we can not get with also instead of it??

Answer (score 23):

- Both function returns receiver object itself.
- They differ in accessing the receiver object.

[image]

It is your decision which one to use. However, in Kotlinlang's website https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html, there is a convention for their usage

Use **also** for additional actions that don't alter the object, such as logging or printing debug information.

```
val numbers = mutableListOf("one", "two", "three")
 numbers
     .also { println("The list elements before adding new one: $it") }
     .add("four")
```

The common case for **apply** is the object configuration.

```
val adam = Person("Adam").apply {
    age = 32
    city = "London"        
}
println(adam)
```