# Kotlin standard functions: run, with, let, also and apply

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to understand the correct use of the functions (run, with, let, also, apply). Let's say we have the following initial code (I am using it for testing purposes):

```
con = urlGet.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
con.readTimeout = 10000
con.connectTimeout = 2000 
con.requestMethod = "GET"
con.doInput = true
con.connect()
inst = con.inputStream
```

According to this [image](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*pLNnrvgvmG6Mdi0Yw3mdPQ.png) I modified it to:

```
con = urlGet.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
inputStream = con.run {
   readTimeout = 10000
   connectTimeout = 2000
   requestMethod = "GET"
   doInput = true
   // Start the query
   connect()
   inputStream
}
```

But according to some guides I found, I think that I am doing multiple "jobs" there.

- modify the initial con object
- run some more functions (connect)
- get another object back (inputstream)

So, I am feeling that this is more correct:

```
    con = urlGet.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    con.apply {
           readTimeout = 10000
           connectTimeout = 2000
           requestMethod = "GET"
           doInput = true
        }
    inputStream = con.run {
           // Start the query
           connect()
           inputStream
        }
```

Are those functions so strictly separated?
Are there any guides (official or not) on how to use these functions?

Comment: One general idiom is to use `apply` inline: `con = (urlGet.openConnection() as HttpUrlConnection).apply { ... }`. It's like extending the initialization procedure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582732/when-should-we-use-let-also-apply-takeif-takeunless-in-kotlin?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official guildelines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#using-scope-functions-applywithrunalsolet) you should be using `run` because you return a different value from the block. So your first code is correct:

```
con = urlGet.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
inputStream = con.run {
   readTimeout = 10000
   connectTimeout = 2000
   requestMethod = "GET"
   doInput = true
   // Start the query
   connect()
   inputStream
}
```